# Autoblocking brute force attacks in DirectAdmin CentOS

Tags: centos, directadmin

I followed this guide ( http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=380 ) including the optional step to automatically block brute force attacks. But now after a few days of checking I do not notice any automatic IP blocking. What might be going on?

I've already tried restarting directadmin, redownloading the files (+ resetting rights). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled brute force login detection system on your server ?

To enable this feature, go to:

Admin Level -> Admin Settings -> Blacklist IPs for excessive login attempts

Comment: Yes, this in enabled.